# Count islands in a binary grid

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell

This is the [No of Island](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/) code challenge.
Please review my implementation in Haskell. I know there must be some better way of doing this.

> Given an m x n 2D binary grid grid which represents a map of '1's
> (land) and '0's (water), return the number of islands.
>
> An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent
> lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the
> grid are all surrounded by water.

#### Input:

```
1  1  1  1  0
1  1  0  1  0
1  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
```

#### Output:

```
1
```

---

## Solution:

```
-- leetcode number of island
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Maybe
{--
1  1  1  1  0
1  1  0  1  0
1  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
--}
data Visited = N | O deriving (Eq, Show)
data Cell = Cell Int Int Visited deriving (Show)
-- Function to compare the cells
instance Eq Cell where
    (==) (Cell r0 c0 _) (Cell r1 c1 _) = r0 == r1 && c0 == c1

-- main function takes the Vector Vector Int
islands :: V.Vector (V.Vector Int) -> [Cell]
islands v = islandhelper1 (0,0) []
    where
        -- fetch the row
        islandhelper1 :: (Int, Int) ->  [Cell] -> [Cell]
        islandhelper1 b@(r, c) cell = case v V.!? r of
            Just x -> islandhelper2 x b  cell
            _ -> cell
        -- fetch the cell and then call neighbors on it
        islandhelper2 :: V.Vector Int -> (Int, Int) ->  [Cell] -> [Cell]
        islandhelper2 rw (r, c)  cells = case rw V.!? c of
            Just 1 -> islandhelper2 rw (r, c + 1)  (getNeighbors v (r,c) cells)
            Just 0 -> islandhelper2 rw (r, c+ 1)  cells
            _ -> islandhelper1 (r + 1, 0)  cells

-- fetch the neighbors
-- add initial cell and neighboring cells
getNeighbors:: V.Vector (V.Vector Int) -> (Int, Int) -> [Cell] -> [Cell]
getNeighbors v (r, c) clls =   initcl ++ getnbs4
    where
        getnbs4:: [Cell]
        getnbs4 = catMaybes $ map clfilter [(0,1),(1, 0),(0, -1),(-1, 0)]
        clfilter:: (Int, Int) -> Maybe Cell
        clfilter (r', c') = let m = r' + r
                                n = c' + c
            in case getCellValue v (m, n) of
                Just (1, cl@(Cell m' n' _)) -> if cl `elem` clls then Nothing else Just (Cell m' n' O)
                _ -> Nothing
        initcl :: [Cell]
        initcl = case getCellValue v (r,c) of
            Just (1, cl@(Cell m' n' _)) -> if cl `elem` clls then clls else ((Cell m' n' N) : clls)
            _ -> clls

-- get the cell value
getCellValue::V.Vector (V.Vector Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Maybe (Int, Cell)
getCellValue v (r, c) = case v V.!? r of
    Just x -> case x V.!? c of
        Just m -> Just (m, Cell r c O)
        _ -> Nothing
    _ -> Nothing


-- to Filter the cell based on N
isNew :: Cell -> Bool
isNew (Cell _ _ k) = k == N

-- Converts list to vector
ltoV :: [a] -> V.Vector a
ltoV = V.fromList

-- converts the String to Int vector
conV :: String -> V.Vector Int
conV = ltoV . map (read::String -> Int) . words

main::IO()
main = do
    content <- ltoV . ( map conV)  . lines <$> readFile "noofisland.txt"
    print $ length . filter isNew $ islands content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit: all of the below was premature.

The basic algorithm you're using doesn't work. Try this test case:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

The usual comments of Code Review apply: Use a linter. Name things clearly. (You've got at least one test case, so that's good!)

Some Haskell-specific code-smell stuff also applies:

- `Visited` is used like a `Bool`, so let it be a `Bool`. (You can wrap it up various different ways for clarity though!)
- At the same time, your use of `Int` to represent the land/water distinction isn't great. What if a `3` snuck in by mistake? Again, wrap up a bool!
- Use record types to name data fields.
- I suggest using type applications for things like `read` instead of an inline type hint.
- There's probably a better way to write `getCellValue` using lenses, but in this case I'd leverage the `Maybe` monad.
- In general, learning more abstractions will be good. For example, if I introduce a `Coordinates` type to wrap up `(Int, Int)`, I can make it an instance of `Semigroup` and `Monoid`.
- `getCellValue` returns a lot of redundant data; simplify it down to just get the *new* stuff. This will push a little extra complexity up into the places where it's used, but the complexity *belongs* there (and can be resolved there).

With respect to the algorithm: Instead of checking if each element is already in the list, consider always adding everything and then using `nub` at the end. This relies on the specific behavior of `nubBy` (it keeps the first match). So the code does get a little more fragile, but it enables substantial simplification!

Also, in your list of ±1 offsets, there's no reason to be searching backward; you already checked those cells!

I've been a bit lazy documenting my process, but the above got me to

```hs
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (nubBy)
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Vector as V

newtype Terrain = Terrain{isLand :: Bool}

data Coordinates = Coord{row :: Int, column :: Int} deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
instance Semigroup Coordinates where
  (Coord r1 c1) <> (Coord r2 c2) = Coord (r1 + r2) (c1 + c2)
instance Monoid Coordinates where
  mempty = Coord 0 0
incementColumn :: Coordinates -> Coordinates
incementColumn (Coord r c) = Coord r (c + 1)

data Cell = Cell {
  coordinates :: Coordinates,
  isNew :: Bool
} deriving (Show)

islands :: V.Vector (V.Vector Terrain) -> Int
islands oceanscape = length . filter isNew . nubBy ((==) `on` coordinates) . reverse $ islandhelper1 mempty []
    where
        islandhelper1 :: Coordinates -> [Cell] -> [Cell]
        islandhelper1 coord cells = case oceanscape V.!? row coord of
            Just rowVector -> islandhelper2 rowVector coord cells
            _ -> cells
        islandhelper2 :: V.Vector Terrain -> Coordinates -> [Cell] -> [Cell]
        islandhelper2 rowVector coord cells = case rowVector V.!? column coord of
            Just (Terrain True) -> islandhelper2 rowVector (incementColumn coord) (getNeighbors oceanscape coord ++ Cell coord True : cells)
            Just (Terrain False) -> islandhelper2 rowVector (incementColumn coord) cells
            _ -> islandhelper1 (Coord{row = row coord + 1, column = 0}) cells

getNeighbors:: V.Vector (V.Vector Terrain) -> Coordinates -> [Cell]
getNeighbors oceanscape coord = mapMaybe (clfilter . (coord <>) . uncurry Coord) [(0,1), (1,0)]
  where clfilter :: Coordinates -> Maybe Cell
        clfilter coord' = do  -- The Maybe Monad!
          Terrain True <- oceanscape !? coord'  -- pattern match failure will yield Nothing.
          return $ Cell coord' False

-- get the cell value
(!?) :: V.Vector (V.Vector a) -> Coordinates -> Maybe a
oceanscape !? coord = do  -- The Maybe Monad!
  x <- oceanscape V.!? row coord
  x V.!? column coord
```

At this point we can see that the entire recursive structure of `islands` is just generating 0-5 items for each step of an iteration, so let's use `fmap`. (Even if we did need to be examining the accumulator, we could still use a fold.)

Here's my final version. I'm pretty sure there's a better way to build `locations`, but I gotta go do actual work :) There are probably even better ways of thinking about the whole problem, but at that point we'd be changing your fundamental algorithm, so that's out of scope.

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (nubBy)
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Vector as V

newtype Terrain = Terrain{isLand :: Bool}

data Coordinates = Coord{row :: Int, column :: Int} deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
instance Semigroup Coordinates where
  (Coord r1 c1) <> (Coord r2 c2) = Coord (r1 + r2) (c1 + c2)

data Cell = Cell {
  coordinates :: Coordinates,
  isNew :: Bool
} deriving (Show)

islands :: V.Vector (V.Vector Terrain) -> Int
islands oceanscape = length . filter isNew . nubBy ((==) `on` coordinates) $ islandHelper `concatMap` locations
  where islandHelper :: (Coordinates, Terrain) -> [Cell]
        islandHelper (coord, Terrain True) = Cell coord True : getNeighbors oceanscape coord
        islandHelper (_, Terrain False) = []
        locations :: V.Vector (Coordinates, Terrain)
        locations = do  -- The Vector Monad!
          (rowIndex, rowVector) <- V.generate (length oceanscape) id `V.zip` oceanscape
          (columnIndex, value) <- V.generate (length rowVector) id `V.zip` rowVector
          return (Coord{row=rowIndex, column=columnIndex}, value)

getNeighbors:: V.Vector (V.Vector Terrain) -> Coordinates -> [Cell]
getNeighbors oceanscape coord = mapMaybe (clfilter . (coord <>) . uncurry Coord) [(0,1), (1,0)]
  where clfilter :: Coordinates -> Maybe Cell
        clfilter coord' = do  -- The Maybe Monad!
          Terrain True <- oceanscape !? coord'  -- pattern match failure will yield Nothing.
          return $ Cell coord' False

-- get the cell value
(!?) :: V.Vector (V.Vector a) -> Coordinates -> Maybe a
oceanscape !? coord = do  -- The Maybe Monad!
  x <- oceanscape V.!? row coord
  x V.!? column coord

main::IO()
main = do
    content1 <- parse <$> readFile "code_review_283543_1.test"
    print $ islands content1
    content2 <- parse <$> readFile "code_review_283543_2.test"
    print $ islands content2
    content3 <- parse <$> readFile "code_review_283543_3.test"
    print $ islands content3
    content4 <- parse <$> readFile "code_review_283543_4.test"
    print $ islands content4
    content8 <- parse <$> readFile "code_review_283543_8.test"
    print $ islands content8
  where parse :: String -> V.Vector (V.Vector Terrain)
        parse = V.fromList . map (V.fromList . map parseCell . words) . lines
        parseCell = Terrain . (/= 0) . (read @Int)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. This helps a lot.